# rcptt not working with java 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I downloaded rcptt 64 bit version 2.2 and it is not working. I selected eclipse or my application as AUT i get same error.
The java version is 1.8
The error log has been attached.

[image: Error Log part 1]
[image: Error Log part 2]

Comment: I dont have 10 reputation points to embed images

Comment: In general, it would be better to post the most relevant error (which is not the entire stack trace) as text, rather than as an image in any event.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Java 1.8. As you can see from the log, the application can not start properly; it can not find some bundles.

You should inspect the launch configuration you are referencing at "Eclipse Application under Test".